# Music status not showing on Conky/MOC?

Tags: sound, 22.04, music, conky

I am installing Graffias theme on Conky but the music not showing what is played on Rhytmbox. I am also looking for a way that those display anything that play on Firefox/Discord etc just for the aesthetic. Trying to configure using ConkyManager2 but there is no option for music.

[image: No music played]

--
UPDATE: after looking on config file, there is this code:

```
${offset 0}${voffset 40}${font Material:size=9}${if_running mocp} ${font Carlito:size=11}${moc_state} :${else}${font Material:size=9} ${font Carlito:size=11}No music played${endif}
${offset 0}${voffset 5}${font Metropolis black:size=15}${if_running mocp}${moc_artist}${else}${font}
${offset 0}${voffset 2}${font Carlito:size=11}${if_running mocp}${moc_song}${else}
```

Basically I need to add code containing Rhythmbox/Firefox/Discord process. The problem is I don't know how to view those process, I take a look at System Monitor but it doesn't show much information to replace **${if_running mocp} ${moc_state} ${moc_song} ${moc_artist}**

I try to change 'mocp' with rhythmbox but it's not working as if it doesn't understand what rhythmbox is. My suspect is that the script can only read a cmd processes?

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the .conf file you will see that the music playing part is referencing `mpd` (Music Player Daemon). I don't know anything about this  myself, it may be as simple as installing `mpd` or may require more conky related tools/setup, but maybe start here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MPD

Comment: I just take a look at theme config file, and it says it will associate what display with moc player. So basically I need to write a new config to show what is playing on firefox/discord/rhytmbox. I don't think installing MPD won't do much since it is a code problem?

Comment: update: I try to change moc into mpd but i still doesn't show music playing